# Transaction control for MySQL in Swing Desktop Application with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, swing, hibernate, transactions

I have a swing Desktop application that uses Hibernate. I can have more than one computer using the application and accesing the same MySQL database concurrently.

I thought that using Hibernate Transaction would prevent the case of two different computers accessing the same data in the same time. Apparently it does not.

The problem i'm facing is similar to this:

```
//Suppose I'm persisting a product sale
Session session = getSession();
Transaction transaction = session.getTransaction();
try {
    transaction.begin();

    MyProduct product = getMyProduct();

    product.setActualInventory(product.getActualInventory() - amountSold);

    session.merge(product);

    transaction.commit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    transaction.rollback();
    logger.error(ex);
    throw new DefaultException("Erro ao salvar a venda.");
}
```

The problem is that sometimes I get this "ActualInventory" not correct, because of multiple access of two machines in the same time.

I thought that with this code, when one computer asked for transaction.begin(), it would have to wait the another one to finish its with transaction.commit().

But now I realized that this does not occur, because I have two different computers with a separate Hibernate in each one that just communicates with the same database.

How could I solve this problem? Maybe is there a way to perform this "transaction control" via MySQL directly?

Comment: Transactions don't block each other, even when started from the same VM. If you're trying to have an exception if two transactions modify the same entity at the same time, then use optimistic locking: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e2764. Also, your call to merge() is useless. Modifications to attached entities are automatically persisted. No need for merge.

Comment: But even in this case where I have two separate machines with Hibernate running, optimistic locking will work?

Comment: It will do what it's documented to do: throw an exception if a A updates an entity that has been modified by B since A initially loaded the entity. You should describe what you want to achieve, and not just say "I want my code to work" without saying what "work" means.

Comment: That is impossible, and not desirable. A single, long transaction would prevent any other transaction do do its job. Databases are optimized to allow concurrent access, to make sure that never happens.

Comment: By "work" I mean to force hibernate to wait until the other transaction is finished. But my worry is that one session does not know about the existence of the other. 
For example, when you say A and B, you mean Session A and Session B, right? Supposing these two sessions exist in the same Hibernate "instance".
But in my case, I have a session A in a Hibernate instance in one computer and another Session B in another hibernate instance from another computer. Could you understand my doubt? Sorry if I was not clear initially.

Comment: By A and B, I mean any session, on any JVM. Yes, optimistic locking will detect a conflicting change and throw an exception when that happens, wherever this change comes from.